# when i am running my code in flask url is not coming in flask phython

Tags: python, flask, url

- Restarting with stat
  The Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: 129-117-983

and it's not showing me the url.When I am running my code in Flask, the url is not coming in Flask Phython.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**In short — it will not show you the url.**

When you have `app.run(debug=True)` and make a change to you python file (or any python files that you import in file that contains you flask) the program would be **restarted** (as seen in your commentary), but url will not be printed in the terminal.

In order to see the url, you would need to exit the python script by pressing "CTRL-C" and run the code again.